# Not able to lay out Subviews on a custom UIView in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, frame, subview

So I have created this custom container view which I am laying out using autolayout constraint.

```
    func configureSegmentContainerView() {
    segmentContainerView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 40).isActive = true
    segmentContainerView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor, constant: 8).isActive = true
    segmentContainerView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor, constant: -8).isActive = true
    segmentContainerView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 3).isActive = true 
    }
```

In the view controller, the `viewDidLoad()` is this:

```
    setupDataSource()
    segmentContainerView = ATCStorySegmentsView()
    view.addSubview(segmentContainerView)
    configureSegmentContainerView()
    segmentContainerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    segmentContainerView.numberOfSegments = friendStory.count
```

Now once the data source is setup and I have the `friendStory` count, I am assigning it to `segmentContainerView.numberofSegments`

In `segmentContainerview` class this is what is happening:

```
    var numberOfSegments: Int? {
    didSet {
        addSegments()
    } 
  }
```

In `addSegments()`, I am adding UIViews depending upon the n`umberOfSegments` this is the code for that:

```
 private func addSegments() {
    guard let numberOfSegments = numberOfSegments else { return }
    layoutIfNeeded()
    setNeedsLayout()
    for i in 0..<numberOfSegments {
        let segment = Segment()
        addSubview(segment.bottomSegment)
        addSubview(segment.topSegment)
        configureSegmentFrame(index: i, segmentView: segment)
        segmentsArray.append(segment)
    }
}

private func configureSegmentFrame(index: Int, segmentView: Segment) {
    guard let numberOfSegments = numberOfSegments else { return }
    let widthOfSegment : CGFloat = (self.frame.width - (padding * CGFloat(numberOfSegments - 1))) / CGFloat(numberOfSegments)

    let i = CGFloat(index)
    
    let segmentFrame = CGRect(x: i * (widthOfSegment + padding), y: 0, width: widthOfSegment, height: self.frame.height)
    segmentView.bottomSegment.frame = segmentFrame
    segmentView.topSegment.frame = segmentFrame
    segmentView.topSegment.frame.size.width = 0
}
```

**Question and Issue: ** Instead of getting 4 UIViews, I am getting 3, but the third one is not correctly placed and is going outside the parent container. How can I get these uiviews aligned correctly. I am guessing there is some issue with where `setNeedsLayout()` and `layoutIfNeeded()` needs to be called. Please help.

`Segment` is a struct with two properties - bottomSegment and topSegment. Both being UIView

[image]

You can see how just three UIView segments appear. I needs to 4 (`numberOfSegments` = 4) of these. Also I am giving the parent container constant of 8 and -8 for `right and leftAnchor`. so all 4 segments need to be placed within this view. As you can see in the picture above the last segment is going outside of the parent container.

Comment: issues is in your configureSegmentFrame method with your logic place debugger and check it step by step.

Comment: This looks like an ideal case for `UIStackView` - have you looked at that?

Comment: Not yet. Let me try stackview and see if that improves anything

Comment: @AbuUlHassan sending the data source in viewDidLayoutSubviews lays out the views perfectly. But I don't want to use ViewDidLayoutSubviews to send the data source info. What to do now.

Comment: In that case user observers ....

Answer (score 0):

Try to call `addSegments` at `onViewDidAppear`. If it works, it means that in your code the view does not still have the correct frame.

For this to work you need to adapt the frames of the views, when the view controller's view changed:

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
     super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
     guard let numberOfSegments = numberOfSegments else { return }
     for i in 0..<numberOfSegments {
        configureSegmentFrame(index: i, segmentView: segment)
    }
}
```

You will probably have to do it cleaner, but it should work.

Comment: Thats understood. I have tried calling it in viewDidLayoutSubviews. But since the view controller is in pageviewcontroller, it effects animations etc. However, I would want to call addSegments probably somewhere other than viewDidLayoutSubviews(). This question deals with this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56671161/sending-datasource-information-only-when-uiview-has-been-laid-out

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that

```
let widthOfSegment : CGFloat = (self.frame.width ...
```

is being called *too soon*. You cannot do anything in that depends upon `self` having its frame until after it *has* its real frame.

For a UIView, that moment is after `layoutSubviews` has been called for the first time.