# Sending datasource information only when UIView has been laid out?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, datasource, subview

I am having trouble understanding this. I have been able to do such a project earlier on but now a similar approach isn't working for me.

Here is the issue:
I have a UIPageViewController that has 4 `storyViewControllers`.
Each `storyViewControllers` has a custom `containerView`. I want to add 'n' number of `UIViews` on the `containerView`. I am sending the `dataSource` or 'n' from the view controller. However, I am not able to correctly lay out the subviews on the container view.

Essentially I want to know when to send the datasource info from the view controller. Obviously I would like to send it once the custom container view has been added.

I am using `viewDidLayoutSubviews`. This makes it work. However, I don't think it's the correct way. Now every time the view controller lays out subviews my delegate will be called.

I have tried doing it in `viewDidLoad()` but that doesn't work either.

This works. But just doesn't seem right. Als
My `storyViewController` code

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    segmentContainerView = ATCStorySegmentsView()
    view.addSubview(segmentContainerView)
    configureSegmentContainerView()
    segmentContainerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

}

  override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    segmentContainerView.delegate = self
     DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.5) {
        self.segmentContainerView.startAnimation() // I am also animating these views that are laid on the containerView. Doing them here starts the animation randomly whenever I scroll through the UIPageController
    }
}
```

In the `containerView`:

```
    var delegate: ATCSegmentDataSource? {
    didSet {
        addSegments()
    }
}

private func addSegments() {
    let numberOfSegment = delegate?.numberOfSegmentsToShow()
    guard let segmentQuantity = numberOfSegment else { return }
    layoutIfNeeded()
    setNeedsLayout()
    for i in 0..<segmentQuantity {
        let segment = Segment()
        addSubview(segment.bottomSegment)
        addSubview(segment.topSegment)
        configureSegmentFrame(index: i, segmentView: segment)
        segmentsArray.append(segment)
    }


}

private func configureSegmentFrame(index: Int, segmentView: Segment) {
    let numberOfSegment = delegate?.numberOfSegmentsToShow()
    guard let segmentQuantity = numberOfSegment else { return }

    let widthOfSegment : CGFloat = (self.frame.width - (padding * CGFloat(segmentQuantity - 1))) / CGFloat(segmentQuantity)

    let i = CGFloat(index)

    let segmentFrame = CGRect(x: i * (widthOfSegment + padding), y: 0, width: widthOfSegment, height: self.frame.height)
    segmentView.bottomSegment.frame = segmentFrame
    segmentView.topSegment.frame = segmentFrame
    segmentView.topSegment.frame.size.width = 0

}
```

This works the way it should. But when I scroll the UIPageViewController, the animations don't always start from the beginning. Since it relies on laying out subviews. Sometimes if I slowly scroll through the page controller then the subviews are laid out again and the animation starts from start. Other times when the views are already loaded, the animations starts from where I left out.

**Question** I want to know what is the best way to send datasource from view controller to the containerView? That datasource is what will be needed to generate the amount of views to be added on the containerView.

This is the result I get, if I send the datasource from `viewDidLayoutSubviews`. I have asked another question earlier today that lists other methods I used to send datasource. Take a look at that as well: [Not able to lay out Subviews on a custom UIView in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56665550/not-able-to-lay-out-subviews-on-a-custom-uiview-in-swift?noredirect=1#comment99903103_56665550)

[image]

Comment: Make use of auto-layout instead of trying to calculate dimensions. As I commented on your other question, a `UIStackView` will probably do exactly what you want ***without*** the need for any frame calculations.

Comment: @DonMag I would still need the datasource info for that too. For example how many UIViews I need to create and then add them to the stackView. My main question here is at what point should I send the datasource info to the child uiview from controller. Anything other than 'viewDidLayoutSubviews()'

Comment: Basically, when using auto-layout constraints, you can add your subviews and setup the constraints in `viewDidLoad()`. After that, auto-layout handles the actual sizing for you - doesn't matter if the device is small or large, portrait or landscape. You haven't shown what you're trying to do with *"animations"*, but it sounds like you would want to start any animations in `viewDidAppear()`.

Comment: @DonMag Completely understood. Basically the reason why I am using frames instead of UIStackView and auto-layout is that I am calculating frames by the frame width and the number of items in the array. Also I am using a struct called segments that contains two UIViews / bottom and top View. The bottom and top Views are both given same frames, but topView width is 0. 
Then I animate the topView from 0 to bottomView.width. 
It just seemed that frames would work better in the way I am animating and doing it. What do you think?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a very basic example...

It has:

- a `Segment: UIView` sub-class that holds a "bottomSegment" and a "topSegment"
- a `ATCStorySegmentsView: UIView` sub-class with a `UIStackView` to layout the desired number of segments
- a `StoryViewController: UIViewController` sub-class that adds `ATCStorySegmentsView` at the top of its view, and then tells that view to animate the first segment on `viewDidAppear()`

---

```
class Segment: UIView {

    let topSegment: UIView = {
        let v = UIView()
        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        v.backgroundColor = .white
        return v
    }()

    let bottomSegment: UIView = {
        let v = UIView()
        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        v.backgroundColor = .gray
        return v
    }()

    var startConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint()
    var endConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint()

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    func commonInit() -> Void {
        addSubview(bottomSegment)
        addSubview(topSegment)

        // start constraint has width of Zero
        startConstraint = topSegment.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomSegment.widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.0)

        // end constraint has width of bottomSegment
        endConstraint = topSegment.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomSegment.widthAnchor, multiplier: 1.0)

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([

            // bottomSegment constrained to all 4 sides
            bottomSegment.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor),
            bottomSegment.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor),
            bottomSegment.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor),
            bottomSegment.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor),

            // topSegment constrained top, bottom and leading
            topSegment.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor),
            topSegment.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor),
            topSegment.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor),

            // activate topSegemnt width constraint
            startConstraint,

            ])
    }

    func showTopSegment() -> Void {
        // deactivate startConstraint
        startConstraint.isActive = false
        // activate endConstraint
        endConstraint.isActive = true
    }

}

protocol ATCSegmentDataSource {
    func numberOfSegmentsToShow() -> Int
}

class ATCStorySegmentsView: UIView {

    let theStackView: UIStackView = {
        let v = UIStackView()
        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        v.axis = .horizontal
        v.alignment = .fill
        v.distribution = .fillEqually
        v.spacing = 4
        return v
    }()

    var segmentsArray: [Segment] = [Segment]()

    var delegate: ATCSegmentDataSource? {
        didSet {
            addSegments()
        }
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    func commonInit() -> Void {
        addSubview(theStackView)

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([

            // constrain stack view to all 4 sides
            theStackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor),
            theStackView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor),
            theStackView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor),
            theStackView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor),

            ])
    }

    private func addSegments() {
        let numberOfSegment = delegate?.numberOfSegmentsToShow()
        guard let segmentQuantity = numberOfSegment else { return }

        // add desired number of Segment subviews to teh stack view
        for _ in 0..<segmentQuantity {
            let seg = Segment()
            seg.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            theStackView.addArrangedSubview(seg)
            segmentsArray.append(seg)
        }
    }

    func startAnimation() -> Void {

        // this will animate changing the topSegment's width
        self.segmentsArray.first?.showTopSegment()
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.5, animations: {
            self.layoutIfNeeded()
        })

    }


}

class StoryViewController: UIViewController, ATCSegmentDataSource {

    let segmentContainerView: ATCStorySegmentsView = ATCStorySegmentsView()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        view.backgroundColor = .red

        view.addSubview(segmentContainerView)

        segmentContainerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([

            // constrain segmentContainerView to top (safe-area) + 20-pts "padding",
            segmentContainerView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: 20.0),

            // leading and trailing with "padding" of 20-pts
            segmentContainerView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            segmentContainerView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor, constant: -20.0),

            // constrain height to 10-pts
            segmentContainerView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 10.0),

            ])

        // set the delegate
        segmentContainerView.delegate = self

    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        segmentContainerView.startAnimation()
    }

    func numberOfSegmentsToShow() -> Int {
        return 3
    }

}
```

---

Result (the white bar animates across the gray bar when the view appears):

[image]

[image]

With 5 segments:

[image]

Note that, as auto-layout is designed to do, it also handles size-changes, such as when the device is rotated:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. That cleared a lot of concepts. Thanks a bunch!